# Qu'est ce que ça veut dire, « Ne s'y frotta plus » ?

Tags: sens, expressions, littérature

En lisant le chef-d’œuvre de Flaubert-*Madame Bovary*- je suis tombé sur une expression dont le sens ne se trouve pas dans les dictionnaires, peut-être qu'elle est une expression obsolète:

> Elle lui avait répondu d'un œil si colère et avec un sourire tellement
> froid, que la bonne femme **ne s'y frotta plus**.

Je voudrais savoir:

- Qu'est que ça veut dire cette expression?
- S'utilise-t-elle dans le Français d'aujourd'hui ou non?

Answer (score 2):

Bonjour,
voila la défénition :

https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/se_frotter/35427

C'est à utiliser dans le sens familier de l'expression  :

> S'en prendre à quelqu'un, l'attaquer, le provoquer.

Donc là en l'occurrence, elle ne veut plus avoir à faire à cette personne.

L'expression est encore utilisée de nos jours.

Answer (score 2):

Se frotter à quelque chose ou à quelqu'un s'utilise toujours, en particulier dans l'expression:

> Qui s'y frotte s'y pique.

La citation de Flaubert est présente dans le TLFi

[Frotter](https://cnrtl.fr/definition/frotter)

> **Se frotter à qqn, à qqc**. S'attaquer à quelqu'un de dangereux, se mêler d'une affaire qui comporte des risques. *Il vaut mieux ne pas s'y frotter. Elle lui avait répondu d'un œil si colère et avec un sourire tellement froid, que la bonne femme ne s'y frotta plus* (Flaub., *M<sup>me</sup> Bovary*, t. 1, 1857, p. 75).